# Bacula backup service

Tags: 12.04

I have been given a project to install bacula and backup a linux ubuntu system.

Can someone help me with the step by step commands and explanation on how to install bacula?
How to backup then how to crash test it and lastly back it up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Bacula, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install bacula
```

For more information on backing up, and other configuration, see [Bacula](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/bacula.html), [Bacula Introduction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bacula), and of course their [website](http://www.bacula.org/en/).

Comment: Just out of curiosity. what's wrong with it?